# Manage dependency of dependencies with Bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, bower

I have an Angular app with has certain bower dependencies.

angular-gridster has in its `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
        "jquery-ui": "*",
}
```

That meant that a computer that hadn't updated in a while, has an older version of jquery-ui.

Coincidentally enough, that version of jquery-ui works, whilst the newer one doesn't.

For a quick fix, we would like to force to gridster to use the older version?

I guess I could modify it there in the `bower.json` file, but it seems really hacky, what is the best course of action to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

on your `bower.json` you can do something like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery-ui": "1.0",
    "angular-gridster": "5.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-ui": "1.0"
  }
```